# Show that ABC is a right angled triangle

Tags: vectors

The position vectors of A, B, and C are $\langle 2i+4j-k \rangle$,  $\langle 4i+5j+k \rangle$ and $\langle 3j+6j-3k \rangle$ respectively. Show that ABC is a right Angled triangle?

Comment: Two vectors are perpendicular whenever their dot product equals zero.

Comment: `3j+6j-3k` in $C$ should be $3 \color{red}{i}+6j-3k\,$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the sides are $\,AB=B-A=\langle-2i-j-2k\rangle\,$, $\,BC=C-B=\langle-i+j-4k\rangle\,$, and $CA=A-C=\langle-i-2j+2k\rangle\,$. Their (squared) magnitudes are $|AB|^2=2^2+1^1+2^2=9\,$, $|BC|^2=1^2+1^2+4^2=18\,$, and $|CA|^2=1^2+2^2+2^2=9\,$. Then by Pythagoras' $\;\cdots$